# I want to Float a Image on the Screen

Tags: android

I have a Splash Screen. I started to screen the logo is in the center of the screen after that I want to float the logo up at the top of the screen in the center with slowly when I press the welcome button

Comment: What have you tried? Show some effort.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

Comment: i tried then i asked ....

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a link to your view and change the margins accordingly : (do this in your onClickListener)

```
mView.bottomMargin += 50;
```

or choose from the margin you want. If you want to animate it, create a simple for loop to slowly increment the value (creating a slow transition)

Answer (score 0):

You need this, enjoy.

```
// dont forget findViewById.
ImageView yourImageView;

public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    yourImageView.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            yourImageView.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    yourImageView.getWidth(), yourImageView.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            yourImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}
```